# Recursive function in Python shows irregular behavior - it executes only sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was working on a problem involving looking up historical trading prices. If the price is not available for a timestamp, go back to the previous timestamp and look up the value. However, upon fiddling with recursion limits `sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)`, I found that the recursion part of the code would not execute altogether upon setting a limit too high. So, I set out to investigate this issue further. I wrote a function for printing the n-th n_bonacci series in Python. Here's the code for that

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)


def n_bonacci_series(n,  k=1, memo={}):
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    elif n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        memo[n] = n_bonacci_series(n - 1, k,  memo) + \
            n_bonacci_series(n - 2, k, memo)
        return memo[n]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = n_bonacci_series(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), {})
    print(n)
```

It works well with lower values (1 - 2000). However, it would not execute anything upon going higher, and the terminal would output nothing. I zeroed in on the number where this problem started. It started with 2206. When running the code in Python, I found that it would execute only sometimes. The output is attached below.

```
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
47560826085308642128638691782026383110062745693928884703260494102838475008504779896361090854101455457025401324143044776114166180160702554656438274920361681150989106875091171050407797787515069337246074248523724768358072059714670001942858736056802300373066705493637091637305975712573716191127269704968186479287183399647662677946469037303681204676246925752667295746028054079126466258038707553782482000197471467485598685351978786172553903287644120133460701701937983
@Animesh ➜ scripts python .\metallic_ratios.py 2206 5
@Animesh ➜ scripts
```

I'm using `Python 3.9.7`, my processor is `Intel Core i5 7200U` with 12 GBs of RAM (2133Mhz)

I absolutely do not understand why this is happening. Can someone help me in investigating this issue? If you're running the code in your system, play around with the value of n in order to get to that point of uncertainty, as I think it may have something to do with system configurations.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Change the value of n to something higher, and see if it gives an output. I checked in a friend's PC - there, the threshold was 857. Anything above 857 didn't provide any output. Moreover, can you please share the configurations of your PC?

Comment: On Windows I get a stack overflow exception in Python intermittently around 1996.  Try using `python -X dev script.py 2206 5`.  Python prints the stackoverflow exception.

Comment: If you lower the recursion limit, you can see that you exceed the recursion depth at *limit* - 2.  You're exceeding Python's default stack size when the recursion depth is too high.  I stop getting crashes and start getting Python recursion limit exceptions if I lower the limit to below 1998.

Comment: What's the point of `k`? It never gets used except to pass unchanged to recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly running out of stack space. Recursion is heavily dependent upon the amount of stack memory available for storing previous conditions.

The [thread](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) import allows you to change the amount of stack space; I suggest you try that, then run your recursive function in a new thread.